# Visual Editor for HTML/PHP

Tags: html, php, editor

Specifically, I'd want something that goes more towards a game engine than something like Eclipse or even Notepad++. I just want to make a simple game that's mostly buttons (look up Alter Ego for an example of what I want to make visually) but I can't seem to find anything that's not an all out game engine or a software that's essentially just a fancy text editor. I do know some (very basic) HTML and PHP, but I think what I'm going for is easily within the range of my skills.